# Attempt to trickshoot for building a Select Expression using reflection

Tags: c#, .net-core, lambda, reflection, expression

I'm trying to build a select expression in reflection from string. My beginning is good and my select expression is built correctly from this source:

```
Type entityType = Type.GetType("NameSpacePath.MyEntity");
ParameterExpression xParameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "x");

string propertyPath = "ReferenceProperty.SubReference.Property";
Expression body = propertyPath.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)xParameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);
```

**This work as expected :**
Body output : { x.ReferenceProperty.SubReference.Property }
SelectExpression Final output : x => new { Property = x.ReferenceProperty.SubReference.Property }

So now I have my body expression in a simple way but the probleme is when i try to get a List.
I would like to be able to write somethings like:

```
string propertyPath = "ReferenceProperty.SubReference.PropertyList.Select(y => y.Id)";
```

or

```
string propertyPath = "ReferenceProperty.SubReference.PropertyList.Select(y => new { Id = y.Id })";
```

**This doesn't work as expected :**
Exception : Select(y => y.Id) is not a member of MyEntity
Body output expected : {x.ReferenceProperty.SubReference.PropertyList.Select(....)}

In the .Aggregate tricks, 'Select' is not a member of my type ...

Does anyone have a clever way to help me to perform this task following my logic or should I revise the way I do things to handle the case of a select on a list ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve? Perhaps you should write the output C# you want to output, given some input...

Comment: This is done, hope it's better to understanding

Comment: I don't understand what your Expression should be...instead you gave me a static string, I don't know what to do with it

Comment: My body expression should be exactly the same as the static string ... but with type of Expression, this work until i try to make a .Select() on a List property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`

```
Type entityType = Type.GetType("NameSpacePath.MyEntity");
ParameterExpression xParameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "x");
LambdaExpression e = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(
        new ParameterExpression[] { xParameter }, 
        null, 
        "x.SubReference.PropertyList.Select(y => y.Id)");
```

Comment: Ok looks like Roslyn with CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync.
I wanted to create the expression through "classic" functions and not with packages but it's true that some people have already created wonders and manage many cases that would be complicated for me to manage.
I have already made a comparison between Roslyn and my code and Roslyn is faster so I will go with that.
I willl compare Roslyn with this method and probably go with the fastest one.

I will make a return here.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Aron's answer which helped me to realize that packages are more adequate than "classical" / "home-made" code to create an Expression from a string or a PropertyInfo[].

After comparing Roslyn, **CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync** and **DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda**, I think **EvaluateAsync** is the most convenient in my case.
It is less complicated to manage than **ParseLambda** which requires a lot of work on the string in order to get a correct result.

The performances between both are similar, no winner here.

I expose my solution here if it can help someone :

- Install-Package **Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting**

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, dynamic>> CreateSelectExpression<TEntity>(string select)
{

    Assembly[] assemblies = {
        typeof(TEntity).Assembly,
        Assembly.Load("System.Collections"),
        Assembly.Load("System.Linq"),
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    };

    var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(assemblies);
    options = options.AddImports("System.Linq");

    var taskSelectBuilder = (Task<Expression<Func<TEntity, dynamic>>>)typeof(CSharpScript)
        .GetMethods()
        .First(x => x.Name == nameof(CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync) && x.IsGenericMethod)
        .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(Expression<Func<TEntity, dynamic>>) })
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { select, options, null, null, default(CancellationToken) });

    taskSelectBuilder.Wait();

    return taskSelectBuilder.Result;
}
```

Called with reflection :

```
var selectExpression = (Expression)typeof(NameOfClassContainingTheFunction)
        .GetMethods()
        .First(x => x.Name == nameof(NameOfClassContainingTheFunction.CreateSelectExpression) && x.IsGenericMethod)
        .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { entityType })
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { select });
```

**Edit :**
After further performance tests (100 consecutive calls to different functions), **DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda** seems to be about **2 times faster** than **CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync** to build the same expression.